# Comparing user input string with elements in array of string literals

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having trouble with comparing the user input string with a substring stored in the pointer array.

Is something wrong with the way I've written the `fgets` function?

Here is the function that I'm implementing:

```
void printForIngredient(void){

  char ingredient[50]; 
  printf("Give the name of the ingredient:");
  fgets(ingredient, 50, stdin); 
  //scanf("%s", ingredient);
  int j=1; 

  //traverse through array, look for recipes which are indicated with 0 in front
  //if recipe is found, look at ingredients inside recipe, which are indicated with 1 in front
  //if ingredient matches, print recipe found 
  for(int i=0; i<14; i++){
    if(rawRecipes[i][0]=='0'){
      if(strcmp(&rawRecipes[i+j][1], ingredient) == 0){
        printf("%s\n", &rawRecipes[i][1]); 
        j++;
      }
    }
  }


}
```

and here is the array that the input is being compared to:

```
char *rawRecipes[]={"0Broccoli Coleslaw","1olive oil","1white vinegar","1broccoli","0Creamy Broccoli Salad","1broccoli","1white sugar","1red onion","1white wine vinegar","0Minnesota Broccoli Salad","1eggs","1broccoli","1red onion",""};
```

For example, for an input of

```
broccoli
```

I'm expecting the following output

```
Broccoli Coleslaw
Creamy Broccoli Salad
Minnesota Broccoli Salad
```

***edit***
I just realized the algorithm doesn't work, even after I've changed the code to turn the \n to '\0' at the end of the ingredient inputted by the user. Can someone suggest where the logic error might be?

Comment: From the `fgets` documentation: "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer."

Comment: The first thing you should have done is *print* `ingredient` and see if it's what you expect.  It won't be.  It will end in a newline, which will prevent it from comparing equal to the strings in your recipes array.

Comment: You can use a debugger to run your program line by line while monitoring the values of all variables. That way, you should be able to see that the string `ingredient` contains a newline character, so that it cannot be identical to one of the strings you are comparing it to.

Comment: Is there a way to read in ingredient without the newline at the end?

Comment: @kat: You can easily find the newline character with `strchr( ingredient, '\n' );` Then you can overwrite it with a `'\0'` character, so that the string now ends where the newline was.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` also stores `'\n'` characters, for `strcmp` to return the correct result you must remove this newline character from the inputed strings, a handy function to do this is [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn).

To look for an ingredient inside a recipe you can use [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to compare each word of the recipe with the inputed ingredient.

[**Running sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/SJ_eAvTDI)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> //toupper

void printForIngredient(void);

int main()
{
    printForIngredient();
}

void printForIngredient(void)
{
    char *rawRecipes[] = {"0Broccoli Coleslaw", "1olive oil", "1white vinegar", "1broccoli", "0Creamy Broccoli Salad", "1broccoli", "1white sugar", "1red onion", "1white wine vinegar", "0Minnesota Broccoli Salad", "1eggs", "1broccoli", "1red onion", ""};

    char ingredient[50], *ptr1, temp[50];

    printf("Give the name of the ingredient: ");
    fgets(ingredient, 50, stdin);
    ingredient[strcspn(ingredient, "\n")] = '\0'; //finds '\n' and replaces it with null-terminator
    ingredient[0] = toupper(ingredient[0]);  //capitalize ingredient first letter

    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        if (rawRecipes[i][0] == '0') //only strings beggining in 0 will be compared, make sure this is what you want
        {
            ptr1 = &rawRecipes[i][1];
            strcpy(temp, ptr1);      //copy, can't tokenize string literals
            char *token;
            token = strtok(temp, " "); //tokenize recipe

            while( token != NULL ) 
            {
                if(strcmp(token, ingredient) == 0)
                {
                    printf( " %s\n", ptr1 );
                    break;
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm also not allowed to make changes to the array

Comment: @kat, I removed the second part, it must work, did you include <string> header?

Comment: yes I included the <string> header, the code terminates right after the printf("Give the name of the ingredient"); line

Comment: @kat, the method is bullet proof, the problem must be ahead look here https://onlinegdb.com/HkQ7pEaP8

Comment: Oh, that line worked when I compared ingredients without spaces, I was trying to find the ingredient between recipes without the 1 in front, is there another way to do this?

Comment: @kat So as I understand you want to find the ingredint only if it begins in 0, so do you want the inputed string to have 0 also? I edited the answer to find an ingredient in your list and print it only if it starts in 0, but the ingredint must also have 0, is this what you need?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was very clear, ingredients actually begins with 1, and recipes begin with 0, I wanted to search the array to print a recipe if it has a certain ingredient. So my logic was to go through the list and look for recipes, then look at the ingredients inside the recipe, and if the ingredient matches the user input, I would print the recipe

Comment: @kat, I added two samples, first one finds the ingredient with the need to input the 0, and the other without the 0.

Comment: @kat, so  the sample is what you need?

Comment: @kat, so I think I have the specs correct this time, I edited the answer, there are comments, let me know if it worked for what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211331/discussion-between-kat-and-anastaciu).

Comment: @kat So I was able to look at this today still, I left you a running sample using strtok to find the ingredient inside the recipe, hope it helps.